# Defining a Python class in both Python and C

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am currently learning how to write Python (v3.5) extension modules using the Python C API.  Some operations, like fast numerical work, are best done in C, while other operations, like string manipulation, are far easier to implement in Python.  Is there an agreed-upon way to use both Python and C code to define a new type?

For example, I've written a `Matrix` type in C that supports basic storage and arithmetic operations.   I want to define the `Matrix.__str__` using Python, where string manipulations are much easier and I don't need to worry about cstrings.

I attempted to define the `__str__` method when the module loads in `__init__.py` as follows:

```
from mymodule._mymodule import Matrix;

def as_str(self):
    print("This is a matrix!");

Matrix.__str__ = as_str;
```

When I run this code, I get a `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'matey.Matrix'`.  Is there an acceptable way to do this?  If the solution is to subclass `Matrix` instead, what is the best way to keep my C base classes / Python subclasses organized within a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't try and do object-oriented stuff in C. I'd stick to writing a module which exposes some (stateless) functions.

If I wanted the Python interface to be object oriented, I'd write a class in Python which imports that (C extension) module and consumes functions from it. Maintaining of any state would all be done in Python.

Comment: Structs will probably come in useful for complex data (e.g. matrices). Look into ctypes.Structure

Comment: Good idea.  However, I'm trying to emulate how `numpy` arrays work (just to learn, I know better than to roll my own linear algebra routines in production).  I'd like to store the matrix data in C since copying back and forth would be too slow.

Comment: Yeah - hence my suggestion to use C structs for representing matrix data. You can access those C structs in Python without any "copying back an forth".

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.ifnamemain.com/posts/2013/Dec/10/c_structs_python/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!  (I didn't see your comment before posting mine, you're too fast :) )

Answer (score 0):

You could instead define a `_Matrix` type which you then extend with a traditional OOP approach

```
from mymodule._mymodule import _Matrix;

class Matrix(_Matrix):
    def __str__(self):
        return "This is a matrix!"
```